# Time-resolved JavaScript currency conversion

Tags: javascript, ajax, currency

I would like to convert a set of data consisting of dated expenses into a different currency. The issue: The expenses span a few years, so the fluctuations over this period need to be taken into account.

Is there some AJAX code that allows me to convert currencies like `var usdVal = convert(100, "EUR", "USD", "Aug 18, 2005");` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an "AJAX code" for that, you need an API that will maintain a huge track of currency fluctuations over the years between at least the two currencies of your example.

A quick search led me to this: https://currencylayer.com/

Comment: Of course it is asynchronous data transmission. How else do you think this currencyplayer works?

Comment: I was downvoted for this? I used quotation marks because it felt to me that "ajax code" is a totally abstract and probably missleading way of describing a javascript (or whatever language) library or plugin. I think that this is what you meant in your original post. Anyway, i believe that my reply is helpful enough for you to start investigating your available options, so at least out of respect for SO rules, you should accept :)

Comment: And yes, i know a thing or two about APIs and how currencylayer works. And there is nothing asynchronous there...asynchronous would be the way you decided to consume it, if you used ajax.